# SQL Server 2019: Cannot combine two queries, when 1 parses string

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables (table1 and table2).

Table 2 has a column called `TaskDescription` which has a string with several 'tags' embedded in it. I cannot change how that data is stored, as it comes from a a third party.  I am able to pull out the taskID

I want to grab all of the information from table 1, where table1.id = the result from the above query.  My issue is that the first query returns more than 1 row and I get an error because of this.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = (SELECT 
                       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) <> 0 
                               THEN SUBSTRING(a.em, 1, CHARINDEX('</taskID>', a.em) - 1)
                            ELSE a.em 
                       END id
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT 
                            SUBSTRING(TaskDescription, CHARINDEX('<taskid>', TaskDescription) + 8, LEN(TaskDescription)) em
                        FROM table2
                        WHERE TaskDescription LIKE '%schemaupdate%') a
        )
```

Comment: Please show some data, either example input or the results of the first query. Then explain to us which rows you are expecting to match in the 2nd query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Your table2 contains data in XML format. SQL Server has XQuery to query such data in a very efficient way.

Comment: Chris/Yitzhak.  You are right, I should have had test data ready to go.  The real data, even though test, was way to ugly to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the results of a limiting query that we are using for a lookup has more than 1 record, but we want to use a scalar expression (single value result) then we have 4 options:

1. Check your limiting query on its own, does it return the data you are expecting?

   - Were you expecting a single result?
2. If all the values are the same in the lookup then `DISTINCT` can be satisfactory, it is lower performance than the next option, but it allows you to still detect errors later when the query returns different values.
3. If you do not care about the specific value, or you know that they will always be the same value and you do not need to validate it, you can return `TOP 1`.

   - make sure you set an appropriate `ORDER BY` when using `TOP`
4. Change your query to be set based, either by changing the `=` to an `IN` operator

#### Distinct:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = (SELECT DISTINCT
                       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) <> 0 
                               THEN SUBSTRING(a.em, 1, CHARINDEX('</taskID>', a.em) - 1)
                            ELSE a.em 
                       END id
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT 
                            SUBSTRING(TaskDescription, CHARINDEX('<taskid>', TaskDescription) + 8, LEN(TaskDescription)) em
                        FROM table2
                        WHERE TaskDescription LIKE '%schemaupdate%') a
        )
```

#### TOP 1:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = (SELECT TOP 1
                       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) <> 0 
                               THEN SUBSTRING(a.em, 1, CHARINDEX('</taskID>', a.em) - 1)
                            ELSE a.em 
                       END id
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT 
                            SUBSTRING(TaskDescription, CHARINDEX('<taskid>', TaskDescription) + 8, LEN(TaskDescription)) em
                        FROM table2
                        WHERE TaskDescription LIKE '%schemaupdate%') a
        )
```

#### Set Based (IN):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT 
                       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.em) <> 0 
                               THEN SUBSTRING(a.em, 1, CHARINDEX('</taskID>', a.em) - 1)
                            ELSE a.em 
                       END id
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT 
                            SUBSTRING(TaskDescription, CHARINDEX('<taskid>', TaskDescription) + 8, LEN(TaskDescription)) em
                        FROM table2
                        WHERE TaskDescription LIKE '%schemaupdate%') a
        )
```

Comment: Chris, I should have mentioned that the limiting query was working perfectly and I expected more than 1 row.  I used the last option, "in" and it was exactly what I needed.  thank you for taking the time to put the options, since I didn't post test data